# Mixed effect conditional logistic regression error

Tags: r, conditional-statements, logistic-regression, mixed-models

I am trying to run a conditional logistic regression with a random effect on matched data. Here is how my data is structured :

```
outcome<-c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)
strata_id<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6)
tmax<-c(30.7,31.3,34.7,32.9,28.2,26.0,26.7,26.5,33.5,33.9,35.3,35.5,28.1,29.2,29.4,28.9,31.5,33.8,35.1,34.2,28.3,29.4,30.1,33.7)
cntry_code<-c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C")
data<-as.data.frame(cbind(outcome,strata_id,tmax,cntry_code))
data

  outcome strata_id tmax cntry_code
1        1         1 30.7          A
2        0         1 31.3          A
3        0         1 34.7          A
4        0         1 32.9          A
5        1         2 28.2          A
6        0         2   26          A
7        0         2 26.7          A
8        0         2 26.5          A
9        1         3 33.5          B
10       0         3 33.9          B
11       0         3 35.3          B
12       0         3 35.5          B
13       1         4 28.1          B
14       0         4 29.2          B
15       0         4 29.4          B
16       0         4 28.9          B
17       1         5 31.5          C
18       0         5 33.8          C
19       0         5 35.1          C
20       0         5 34.2          C
21       1         6 28.3          C
22       0         6 29.4          C
23       0         6 30.1          C
24       0         6 33.7          C
```

I want to match on strata_id (fixed effect) and include a random effect for the country that each person lives in. I am using the mclogit package in R and this is the model I specified :

```
model1<-mclogit(cbind(outcome, strata_id)~ns(tmax, df=3), random = ~1|cntry_code, data=data)
```

but I get the error:

```
Error in mclogit(cbind(outcome, strata_id) ~ ns(tmax, df = 3), random = ~1 |  : 
 No predictor variable remains in random part of the model.
 Please reconsider your model specification.
```

I am not sure how to address this error. Should I be using a different method such as glmer or from the lme4 package?

Comment: Isn't this because each `strata` only exists within a single country? If there's only one country per stratum how can country be separated from the strata as a random effect?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the model drops the random term and thus gives the error is because the random term, e.g., cntry_code, does not vary within strata. In other words, for each strata value, the cntry_code is constant.

From the creator of the mclogit package in R (Dr. Martin Elff):
"This is a basic feature of conditional logit: everything that is constant within the conditional logit strata cancels out when the ratio

```
$$
\frac{\exp(\boldsymbold{x}_i\boldsymbol{\beta})}
      {\sum_k\boldsymbold{x}_k\boldsymbol{\beta}}
$$
```

is created.

A random slope term should work and look something like this (insert with own data):

```
random = dependent variable | random term variable
```